# Lwjgl3Application drawing perf degrades from 1.9.10 to 1.9.11

Tags: libgdx

Hi I have a game that was using Lwjgl3Application with 1.9.10, after updating to 1.10.0 the drawing is noticeably worse on my 2014 macbook pro. You can tell the difference even when drawing a single texture. When texture are drawn, it looks like they are drawn in horizontal chunks, giving the illusion that drawing is lagging. The framerate via `Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()` is still ~60. On larger scenes, the weirdness in drawing is very apparent as large horizontal bands of artifacts going across the screen.

I used the project generator tool to make a scratch project to try and narrow it down, it looks like the degradation happens between 1.9.10 and 1.9.11.

In comparison, using `LwjglApplication` works just as well as before.

Below is the code, if running on a mac make sure to add the `-XstartOnFirstThread` VM arg to the desktop launcher otherwise it won't start.

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        final Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();
        new Lwjgl3Application(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    int posX, posY;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, posX, posY);
        batch.end();

        // make texture move around a bit
        posX++;
        posY++;

        if (posX >= Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - img.getWidth()) {
            posX = 0;
            posY = 0;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks